# Selenium IDE rollup rule with gotoIf and label

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

Ok so I'm using the rollup rule in a userextension and for some reason Selenium will keep saying my labels for my gotoIF don't exist. Does anyone has any idea why or how I can fix this problem? The language is JS (JavaScript)

```
var manager = new RollupManager();

manager.addRollupRule({
name: 'FRLanguageCheck'
 , description: 'Check the language to make sure its in french'
 , args: [
 ], commandMatchers: [
 ]
 , getExpandedCommands: function(args) {
 var commands = [];

commands.push({
 command: 'storeTextPresent'
 , target: 'English'
 , value: 'LanguageCheck'
 });
 commands.push({
 command: 'gotoIf'
 , target: '${LanguageCheck}==false'
 , value: 'StepWithWrongLanguage'
 });
commands.push({
 command: 'gotoIf'
 , target: '${LanguageCheck}==true'
 , value: 'StepWithRightLanguage'
 });
 commands.push({
 command: 'label'
 , target: 'StepWithWrongLanguage'
 , value: ''
 });
commands.push({
 command: 'click'
 , target: 'TestLanguageChangeToFrench failed. The site was not in French.'
 , value: ''
 });
 commands.push({
 command: 'label'
 , target: 'StepWithRightLanguage'
 , value: ''
 });
 return commands;
 }
});
```

this is the error messages I get from Selenium

```
[error] [selblocks] Error @1: [rollup|FRLanguageCheck] Target label 'StepWithRightLanguage' is not found.
[warn] [selblocks] __Stack Trace__
[error] Unexpected Exception: Error: @1: [rollup|FRLanguageCheck] Target label 'StepWithRightLanguage' is not found..
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I haven't used selenium with any other language than XML so apologies for any mistakes. Edits are welcome. (is this java?)

You don't need specify both true and false but I do understand your employer may be after something specific. You are going to want to seperate the `gotoIf` statements  because one is going to hide the other.

```
var manager = new RollupManager();

manager.addRollupRule({
name: 'FRLanguageCheck'
 , description: 'Check the language to make sure its in french'
 , args: [
 ], commandMatchers: [
 ]
 , getExpandedCommands: function(args) {
 var commands = [];

commands.push({
 command: 'storeTextPresent'
 , target: 'English'
 , value: 'LanguageCheck'
 });
commands.push({
 command: 'gotoIf'
 , target: '${LanguageCheck}==false'
 , value: 'StepWithWrongLanguage'
 });
 commands.push({
 command: 'label'
 , target: 'StepWithWrongLanguage'
 , value: ''
 });
commands.push({
 command: 'storeTextPresent'
 , target: 'English'
 , value: 'LanguageCheck'
 });
commands.push({
 command: 'gotoIf'
 , target: '${LanguageCheck}==true'
 , value: 'StepWithRightLanguage'
 });
commands.push({
 command: 'click'
 , target: 'TestLanguageChangeToFrench failed. The site was not in English.'
 , value: ''
 });
commands.push({
 command: 'label'
 , target: 'StepWithRightLanguage'
 , value: ''
 });
 return commands;
 }
});
```

I would recommend having only one `gotoIf` statement because currently you only have one command. If you do go with two then you may want to add a string of commands to `StepWithWrongLanguage` so that it changes the language if its in french and then the second `gotoIf` statement can verify that it was actually changed.

Comment: Your script seems right albeith you seem to have inserted }); commands.push({ in one straith line and forgot it on another wich bugs it. I will test it out with that correction.

EDIT: The new command also returns the same bug announcing the label does not exist. When I add the label to Selenium the script runs its course but instead ignore the label entirely going straith for my Click error line. Could it be that rollup cannot use the label command?

Comment: Note: I tried your idea again with a single label and gotoIf but the rollup keep saying the label doesnt exist. If I add said label in the Selenium script it ignores it and jump to the click error line despite yielding a 'true' result.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have only used selenium with xml so I'm still learning. I have adjusted my code so it is better formatted. My apologies. So you are getting the exact same error you were getting before?

Comment: I am it keeps the

    [error] [selblocks] Error @1: [rollup|FRLanguageCheck] Target label 'StepWithRightLanguage' is not found.
    [warn] [selblocks] __Stack Trace__
    [error] Unexpected Exception: Error: @1: [rollup|FRLanguageCheck]    Target label 'StepWithRightLanguage' is not found.

Messagelines

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a solution to this problem I also had, I landed on this blog entry:

http://lance.bio/2017/04/18/selenium-ide-rollups-with-arguments/

and its author (Lance Cleveland) kindly answered my question about using label in rollups (see the comments section). Briefly, in the words of Lance, the problem is this:

> You cannot use some of the custom commands in the rollups. It has to
>   do with how the JavaScript is loaded for the custom commands (those
>   are JavaScript as well) and the scope of the variables commands like
>   labels / goto have set.
>
> However, since rollups are JavaScript anonymous functions you can use
>   any JavaScript trickery you’d like to build the rollup. You can
>   simulate your own gotoIf commands using standard JavaScript if
>   commands. Any stored values are in the storedVars array.

I hope this helps you.